# Balancing clean design against browser limits

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to design an interface to a model (part of an MVC/MVP design) which could represent data stored remotely (on a server) or locally.  To do this requires that my interface be asynchronous, i.e. I will request some data from the model and a callback will provide the actual data.  However, the model could also be stored locally, that is, the request could be satisfied synchronously.

The issue I am running into is that there could conceivably be a lot of calls to the model in order to generate the view, but if the model is synchronous this could result in a stack overflow since each callback is recursing one level deeper and no browser javascript implementations support tail recursion.  I thought about using setTimeout but the minimum delay is 4ms, and anything running into a stack overflow (which under my version of chrome is a bit over 10k) is going to be unacceptably slow using setTimeout (over 40s!) due to all those unnecessary 4ms waits between iterations through the model.

So I'm wondering how to solve this problem and I'm not coming up with any good solutions.  The browser doesn't seem capable of doing what I need it to, and I can't have two different interfaces - one for local and one for remote - because the calling code shouldn't have to care.

Update: Here is the source of the recursion:

I'm using continuation.js to turn synchronous looking code here:

```
function test2() {
    var i
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        AJaX(some_query+i,cont(tab))
        console.log(tab.status)
    }
}
```

Into this:

```
function test2() {
  var i, tab;
  i = 0;
  function _$loop_0(_$loop_0__$cont) {
    if (i < 10) {
      AJaX(some_query + i, function (arguments, _$param0) {
        tab = _$param0;
        console.log(tab.status);
        i++;
      _$loop_0(_$loop_0__$cont);
      }.bind(this, arguments));
    } else {
      _$loop_0__$cont();
    }
  }                                                                                          
  _$loop_0(function () {
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't see why "each callback is recursing one level deeper"? Until we get robust support for something like setImmediate, you can use postMessage to queue fast asynchronous events - e.g. check out this implementation https://npmjs.org/package/asap

Comment: I've updated the question to show an example of how iteration gets turned into recursion.  In the asynchronous case it's not a problem because it gets decoupled.

Comment: @Sacho thanks, I'll take a look at postMessage, that may do what I need...